# Kubernetes fabric8 Java API - How to list StorageClass objects

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

Is there a way to list the Kubernetes StorageClass objects using the fabric8 Java API?

Answer (score 1):

fabric8-Kubernetes Client supports StorageClass from latest release v3.1.10.

You can use the following to get the list of Storage Class

`StorageClassList storageClassList = client.storageClasses().list();`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid that atm this is not possible.

Raised:

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-model/issues/226

and

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/869

so that we can keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

fabric8 kubernetes-client does not support StorageClass yet. This is an open issue on fabric8 kubernetes-client 
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/869

This issue is again dependent on the support for StoageClass in fabric8 kubernetes-model 
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-model/issues/226

Both issues are in "open" status. You can watch for those issues and update the maven dependency version in your pom.xml and use it. Hope this helps.